# Подстановка содержимого файла в URL

Tags: python, python-3.x

Подскажите, как подставить содержимое файла в url-запрос?
Содержимое файла:

```
1
2
3
```

Сейчас пытаюсь вот так:

```
with open('5678.txt', 'r') as file:
        nums = file.read().splitlines()
response = requests.post('https://192.168.55.12/tovar/ostatok/'+nums, headers=headers, verify=False)
```

Но получаю ошибку:

```
TypeError: must be str, not list
```

Надо чтоб URL был вида:

```
https://192.168.55.12/tovar/ostatok/1
https://192.168.55.12/tovar/ostatok/2
https://192.168.55.12/tovar/ostatok/3 и т.д.
```

Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

```
with open('5678.txt', 'r') as file:
    nums = file.read().splitlines()
    for num in nums:
        response = requests.post('https://192.168.55.12/tovar/ostatok/'+num,
                                  headers=headers, verify=False)
        # Здесь что-то делаете с каждым отдельным response
```